# comparison of objects is failing

Tags: python, oop, comparison

I made an object to represent primitive dates (YYYYMM) so that I can add/sub easily (201812 + 1 = 201901) and to for-loop over a range of them. While adding / subtracting or comparison (eq, lt) by themselves are working properly, the for-loop over the rng-function is failing: `'<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetyp6'`

Am I missing something fundamental here? What can I do, so Python will threat the objects like integers?

```
class datetyp6:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = int(value)
        self.yr = int(str(value)[0:4])
        self.mt = int(str(value)[-2:])
        if len(str(value))!=6 or self.mt>12:
            raise ValueError('Invalid Date')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __add__(self, other):
        a = other // 12
        b = other % 12
        if self.mt + b > 12:
            y = self.yr + a+1
            m = self.mt + b-12
        else:
            y = self.yr + a
            m = self.mt + b           
        return int(str(y)+str(m).zfill(2))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        a = other // 12
        b = other % 12
        if self.mt - b < 0:
            y = self.yr - a - 1
            m = self.mt - b + 12
        else:
            y = self.yr - a
            m = self.mt - b           
        return int(str(y)+str(m).zfill(2))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, 'value'):
            return self.value == other.value
        return self.value == other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if hasattr(other, 'value'):
            return self.value < other.value
        return self.value < other


def rng(min, max, step = 1):
    while min < max:
        yield min
        min = min + step

d01 = datetyp6(201610)
d12 = datetyp6(201702)

d01 < d12

for i in rng(d01, d12):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Something like `0 < datetyp6(201610)` will call `int.__lt__` then try `datetyp6.__gt__` when it reverses the arguments, which your class doesn't support. Look into [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) or implement more of the [comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__).

Comment: Thanks. Adding more comparison methods worked. Along with transforming the result within the rng-Function back to datetyp6 `min = datetyp6(min + step)`